# Invokedynamic with non-static context

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, jvm-bytecode

I learnt that `invokedynamic` instruction of bytecode calls a `static` method representation of lambda.

Please let me know if that is incorrect.

if correct, then how is below code working?

```
String[] arr = new String[1];
Stream.of(arr).forEach((s) -> System.out.println(this));
```

Comment: That is certainly not _universally_ true, but it is, on some but not all occasions, roughly how lambdas are implemented.  Are you asking for a general description of `invokedynamic`, an outline of how lambdas are implemented, or...what?

Comment: @LouisWasserman can you please tell the method generated for lambda in question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s not correct to say that lambda expressions were *always* compiled to a `static` method. It’s not specified, how they are compiled, which leaves room for two different strategies for a lambda expression that captures `this`, like your `s -> System.out.println(this)`.

1. use an instance method:

   ```
   private void compiler$chosen$name(String s) {
       System.out.println(this);
   }
   ```
2. use a `static` method:

   ```
   private static void compiler$chosen$name(TypeOfThis var0, String s) {
       System.out.println(var0);
   }
   ```

Both methods work equally well when the `invokedynamic` instruction points to a bootstrap method in the [`LambdaMetafactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html). In either case, the `invokedynamic` instruction will have a signature consuming a `TypeOfThis` instance and producing a `Consumer<String>`. From the documentation of the [`LambdaMetafactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html), you can derive that it will treat the receiver of a non-`static` target method like an implied the first argument, which makes the functional signature of both variants identical. All that matters, is that the argument to the consumer’s `accept` method has to correspond to the *last* argument of the list.

I’ve encountered both strategies in practice, so this is indeed compiler dependent.

Note that these strategies also work on source code level, when using method references:

```
public class Example {
    BiConsumer<Example,String> variant1 = Example::instanceMethod;
    BiConsumer<Example,String> variant2 = Example::staticMethod;

    private void instanceMethod(String s) {
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    private static void staticMethod(Example instance, String s) {
        System.out.println(instance);
    }
}
```

This demonstrates the equivalence of a method receiver and the the first argument to a `static` method. However, when it comes to binding an argument, only `Consumer<String> c = this::instanceMethod;` works with method references. The other binding features of the `LambdaMetafactory` are only used by compiler generated code for lambda expressions.